# awk ignore case isn't working

Tags: awk, aix, ignore-case

I am using this code to get ip entries from host file with ignore case and it doesn't seem to work on AIX

Input file

```
172.23.1.230    enboprtpapzp04.digjam.com  enboprtpapzp04
#172.23.0.33    enboprtpapzp04.digjam.com  enboprt        enboprtpapzp04
172.23.1.230    enboprtpapzp04.fixture.com  enboprtpap    enboprtpapzp04

awk -v client="$client" 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1}{k=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i==client){print $1}; k++}}' file
```

See the output below

```
client=ENBOPRTPAPZP04
awk -v client="$client" 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1}{k=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i==client){print $1}; k++}}' file
```

Nothing comes up

expected output

```
    grep -i ENBOPRTPAPZP04 /etc/hosts | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v "^#"
172.23.1.230
172.23.1.230
```

Comment: And what is the expected output? The ips?

Comment: Why would someone put negative response on the question, its a simple question of IGNORECASE=1 not working, I need to know why, Now how difficult is it as a question to mark it negative?

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks sed not a big problem i can replace it in awk, I am not using gawk, ignorecase works fine in linux but not in AIX, any other way to ignore case in AIX in awk?

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the explanation, I edited the question does it seems ok now? can someone please positive vote it please?

Comment: @EdMorton Seems ok now? Will keep that in mind, was in a rush, can now it be positively voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works here:

```
$ awk -v client="$client" 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1} $2==client && /^[^#]/{print $1}' your_hosts
172.23.1.230
172.23.1.230
```

Are you sure you are using GNU awk? If not, you could:

```
$ awk -v client="$client" 'tolower($2)==tolower(client) && /^[^#]/{print $1}' your_hosts
```

In the light of the resent - whoops, I meant recent - edits to the question and the mentioning of *the loop* in the comments I'll add this:

```
$ awk -v client="$client" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(tolower($i)==tolower(client) && $1!~/^#/)print $1}' your_new_hosts
172.23.1.230
172.23.1.230
```

Also, check @EdMorton's last comment below for a non-looping version.

The check for the `/^#/` could be outside of the action block in the condition part:

```
$ awk ... '!/^#/ {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(tolower($i)==tolower(client)) print $1}' your_new_hosts
```

Comment: it's not GNU awk that is why may its not working however tolower works fine, but the requirement is it's not necessarily second column to be compared it's all column, it could be 3 or 4 and so one that's why I had the loop earlier to compare at each column for the string with ignored case

Comment: That didn't reflect from the output of your `grep`.

Comment: Changed the input output

Comment: @EdMorton grep does a search on entire line, However awk has the capability of searching a pattern on a particular column, I just wanted to do a search of pattern on each column which should be case insensitive

Comment: FWIW chances are `tolower($0) ~ "[[:space:]]"tolower(client)"([[:space:]]|$)"` is all you really need instead of a loop. Good luck!

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks I tried your code, but it gives the output in one single line and doesn't ignores # at the beginning as in grep -v "^#"
`echo $(awk -v client="$client" 'tolower($0) ~ "(^|[[:space:]])"tolower(client)"([[:space:]]|$)' file)`
172.23.1.230 enboprtpapzp04.digjam.com enboprtpapzp04 #172.23.0.33 enboprtpapzp04.digjam.com enboprt enboprtpapzp04 172.23.1.230 enboprtpapzp04.fixture.com enboprtpap enboprtpapzp04

Comment: @Sid The full command is: `awk -v client="$client" '!/^#/ && tolower($0) ~ "[[:space:]]"tolower(client)"([[:space:]]|$)" {print $1}' file`

Comment: @Sid you're getting output in one single line because you're wrapping the output from the command in `echo $(...)`. I can't imagine why you're doing that but - just don't.

Comment: @JamesBrown I can't afford to have ~ i.e contains, need to make exact search on each column, your's is equivalent to grep which I can use, However I am looking for awk solution

Comment: @Sid My code has `~` only to test that the whole record don't start with a `#`. You must be referring to @EdMorton's code which I just spelled out for you.

Comment: @JamesBrown Sorry I didn't check the loop solution you gave, let me check and i believe it should work fine